# getting typerror while importing xarray and odc python packages

Tags: python, python-xarray

packages I imported - >

```
import xarray as xr
from odc.stac import configure_rio, stac_load
```

my error ->

```
TypeError: <class 'numpy.typing._dtype_like._SupportsDType'> is not a generic class
```

can someone please point me to the correct direction for solving this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend not using the latest version xarray as of now. Try pinning it to version 0.20.2.

referenced from:

https://github.com/unit8co/darts/issues/1092

https://github.com/neurolib-dev/neurolib/issues/215

https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/6818

Comment: Thank you for responding and this is the only thing I found everywhere else too. Guess I will go with this for now.